# Using DEAP (genetic algorithm library) with spark

Tags: pyspark, genetic-algorithm, deap

Is IT possible to use DEAP ( http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/) with a spark cluster to map the fitness evaluation function. I would like to run a GA but the fitness function is rather long and I was planning on distributing it on a spark cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [Using Multiple Processors](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part4.html) section in the DEAP documentation and at this [example](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/onemax_island_scoop.py). They explain how to replace the **map** function in the DEAP [toolbox](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html#using-the-toolbox) by a **map** function of your choice.

To use pyspark to map the fitness evaluation function, you could do something like that:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="DEAP")

def sparkMap(algorithm, population):
    return sc.parallelize(population).map(algorithm)

toolbox.register("map", sparkMap)
```