# how to run evolutionary algorithms using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, evolutionary-algorithm, deap

I want to run evolutionary algorithms like GA,PSO using pyspark on spark.How to do this using MLLib using Deap python library.Is there any other library available to perform same task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DEAP (genetic algorithm library) with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607035/using-deap-genetic-algorithm-library-with-spark)

Comment: upvoting for SEO reasons. This question is much easier to find than a very niche and less-known experimental framework called DEAP. Alternatives would also be beneficial since this question is broader than the DEAP question. @usernumber

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065844/3048288) on how to use DEAP with Spark and see if it works for you.

Here is an example of how to configure the DEAP [toolbox](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html#using-the-toolbox) to [replace the map function](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part4.html) by a custom one using Spark.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="DEAP")

def sparkMap(algorithm, population):
    return sc.parallelize(population).map(algorithm)

toolbox.register("map", sparkMap)
```

Comment: What is `toolbox`? Please don't duplicate answers. Provide one good one, then link to it via the comments

Comment: It is an utility class provided by DEAP to make it easy to change operators without impacting the rest of your algorithm (docs [here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html#using-the-toolbox). In my example, it replaces the map function (used to map the fitness function to all the individiduals) by a custom one using Spark parallelize function. You can find another example in the [docs](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part4.html).

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/DEAP/deap/issues/268 they show how to do this in the DEAP package. However this is an issue. but they mention there is a pull request (https://github.com/DEAP/deap/pull/76), and is seems the fixed code/branch is from a forked repo.
It sounds like if you rebuild the package with that code it should resolve the issue.

Another resource I found, haven't tried it, is https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/genetic-algorithms.
Also came across this https://github.com/paduraru2009/genetic-algorithm-with-Spark-for-test-generation